# Error when trying to use Cygwin to compile a makefile in Clion

Tags: c, makefile, clion

I am trying to compile a simple makefile program in C using Clion. I have the most up to date version of Clion and have reinstalled Cygwin and the suggested plugins as referenced by https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-windows.html#Cygwin
However, I keep getting this error:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fj3p.png)
"CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
Cannot run program "make" (in directory "C:\College\Fall2020\COMS 327\coms327p1"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified:
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified"
At first I figured it was just an issue with my make file, however I transferred this project over to linux and ran it from the command line and it works perfectly. So I am not sure why I cannot get this makefile project to run on windows.

For reference I am including my makefile as well:

```
all: gensine gendial

gensine: main.c
    gcc -o gensine main.c -lm

gendial: main2.c
    gcc -o gendial main2.c -lm

clean:
    rm gensine gendial
```

Comment: OT:  regarding statements like; `gcc -o gensine main.c -lm`  when compiling, should always enable the warnings (then fix any warnings)  Suggest: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -o gensine main.c -lm

Comment: Note: the environment: `cgywin` is for running a linux OS on a windows computer.